# Video players with RTSP support

Tags: internet, video-player

I have asked this question first: [What codec/capability is needed for a video player to play (French) TV stations as VLC does?](https://superuser.com/q/1322795/162573) (namely playing TV stations of the French provider Free) and I have received an [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1322807/162573) saying that the main factor is RTSP support.

Therefore, I think this is the proper place to post this question, also with the partial purpose of posting myself an answer based on the linked question and its answer.

---

I am interested in Linux (mostly) but also Windows and Mac video players with that capability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux: Beside **VLC** and **Kaffeine** (as I said in the linked question above), I have received an [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1322807/162573) thereunder mentioning **Totem** player. I have also tested **Dragon** player, and it works, but is less useful, as it lacks a playlist display itself (therefore it can play separate TV stations saved as 1-item playlists but cannot display them as a list and help switch between them like other players can).

In Mac and Windows - I am not aware of another player except **VLC**.